# domain and range of a relation operation in Alloy

Tags: dns, range, relation, alloy, model-checking

Is there any operation that returns range and domain of a relation in Alloy.

Suppose I have a sig defined in Alloy as bellow:

```
sig A {r : B }

sig B {}
```

I am looking for and operation to be applied on r and give me B (probably something like r[B] that returns B)

The above situation might seem stupid as r[B] would return B, so why I am not using B at first place! Actually I find having a range and domain operations(if they ever exist) very useful in writing facts (constraints). e.g.:

```
sig O {sup:O}

sig M{mid: O, sup:O} {mid.sup=sup}

sig F{fid:O, sup:O}{fid.sup=sup}


fact K{
   all o:O | lone so:M | so.mid=o 
   all o:O | lone so:F | so.fid=o
   all o:O | one i:(fid+mid) | o in i[O]   //I want to say fid+mid is injective, so expecting i[O] return range of i
 }
```

any idea? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will find range and domain functions for binary relations in the library module relation.als under the names `ran` and `dom` respectively.  There are brief discussions in sections 3.2.5 and 3.4.3.6 of Daniel Jackson's book on *Software Abstractions*.

On the other hand, you can also do without the library functions.  For any binary relation *r*, the domain and range of *r* can also easily be expressed as *r.univ* and *univ.r*, respectively.  Using the box operator instead of dot, the range can also be expressed as *r[univ]*.  (Note that your example *r[B]* will return nothing, because it's equivalent to *B.r* and nothing in B matches the first item of any pair in R (since the first items are all in A, not B, and in the example A and B are disjoint).  If you want the subset of B which occur in the pairs of r, you want to write *A.r*, or equivalently *r[A]*.  In this case, since the first item in *r* is always an element of *A*, *A.r* is equivalent to *univ.r*.

Note that the words *domain* and *range* have multiple usages.  The term *domain* is used sometimes to denote the set of things which appear as the first item in the pairs of a relation (and *range* similarly for the set of things appearing as the second item in any pair), and sometimes to denote the set of things which *might* appear as the first (second) item in a pair.  Both the library functions and the expressions *r.univ* and *univ.r* evaluate to domains and ranges in the first sense, not the second.  In terms of your first example, in Alloy the domain of the relation *r* is not necessarily equal to the set *B*; it can also be a proper subset of *B*.

---

[Addendum] To check that the relation `fid + mid` is injective, one simple way would be to write

```
fact {
  all o : O | lone x : M + F | x.mid = o or x.fid = o
}
```

Use `one` instead of `lone` if you want to assert that `fid + mid` is also total over `M + F`; I don't understand 'injective' to entail that.

A terser formulation might take a more 'relational' style:

```
lone (mid + fid).o
```

Recast in this idiom, your fact would read

```
fact mid_fid_injective {
  all o : O | lone mid.o
  all o : O | lone fid.o
  all o : O | lone (mid + fid).o
}
```

But of course the first and second statements here are implied by the third, so you could get by with

```
fact mid_fid_injective {
  all o : O | lone (mid + fid).o
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your descriptive response. Now I see that univ keyword not only semantically covers unary relations(unary set universe), but it covers all unary, binary, and ... relations, right? That is why we can write univ.r!
I would like to add that I used **univ.i** in above example, but got an error: "Analysis cannot be performed since it requires higher-order
quantification that could not be skolemized.", but I think this is another story. Thx

Comment: The keyword univ denotes the set of all atoms. It does not include non-singleton tuples.  You may want to read up on the dot (join) operator.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add some comments about the dot operator that would help understanding why r.univ and unive.r are respectively return domain and range of the relation r.

Dot operation in Alloy is similar to composition operation. For describing it assume the following settings:

```
a1 is an arrow /relation from A to B
a2 is and arrow/ relation from B to C
```

Then a1.a2 is an arrow/relation from A to C. In a1.a2 the intermediate elements that belong to B and are in both the range of a1, and domain of a2 are omitted.

In Alloy, dot operation can be used for sets too. 
In above example, if a2 becomes a **univ** (**univ** is a unary set constant which includes all the elements in the model), a1.univ includes elements of A that participate in relation a1 (i.e. domain of a1). The reason is that the intermediary elements (i.e., the elements in univ that matches the range of a1) are all removed. Note that in a1.univ all the a1 range is matched and removed, since univ comprises all the elements in the model including a1 range.

Hope this helps.